# unknown enum constant javax.persistence.CascadeType.DETACH

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping

In my domain code:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "xyz", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DETACH})
@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
private Set<xyzGroup> groups = new HashSet<xyzGroup>();
```

I get following exception when I am trying to build my project(using maven package).

```
in class file (xyz.class) : unknown enum constant javax.persistence.CascadeType.DETACH
```

Why such type of exception is occurred ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CascadeType.DETACH` was added in JPA 2.0. Make sure that your version of Hibernate is 3.5 or above, and that you don't have JPA 1.0 jars in your classpath (run `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` to check it).

Comment: I used hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar

Comment: @Sachin: If you see this error, you have JPA 1.0 jar somewhere in the classpath. You need to find and eliminate it.

Comment: I have checked mvn dependency. No JPA 1.0 jar file found. Is there another reason for occurrence of this type of error ?

Comment: @SachinJ: There are no other reasons. JPA 1.0 jar should be somewhere in classpath.

Comment: JPA 1.0 jar not found in classpath :(

Comment: Actually, my main project have sub projects and the dependency is missing from pom.xml of sub project. Its working now :)